# Filtering a Django model using the related names of 2 M2M fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following structure in my models:

```
class Sauce(models.Model):
    ...

class Topping(models.Model):
    ...

class Pizza(models.Model):
    sauces = models.ManyToManyField(Sauce, related_name='pizzas')
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping, related_name='pizzas')
```

Now, lets say I want to query all the pizzas given a list of toppings and sauces. For example:

```
sauces_ids = [2, 5, 7, 8]
toppings_ids = [1, 4, 5, 21]
```

What is the most efficient way to query this using Django's ORM? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming those are values of `pk`/`id` field, you can use the `__in` lookup:

```
Pizza.objects.filter(sauces__in=sauces_ids, toppings__in=toppings_ids)
```

If those are values of some other field, you need to reference the field name as well, e.g. with field name `field`:

```
Pizza.objects.filter(sauces__field__in=sauces_ids, toppings__field__in=toppings_ids)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Pizza.objects.filter(sauces__source_id__in=[2,5,6,8], toppings__topping_id__in=[1, 4, 5, 21])
```